# What is wrong with this code?

Tags: java, security, encryption

Thanx to evry one help me ..but still there is 2 problem after editing the code

```
import java.io.*;
import java.math.*;
import java.security.*;
import javax.crypto.*;
import javax.crypto.spec.*;

public class RCC4 {
    public RCC4(){} 

    public static void main(String[] args)throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException, InvalidKeyException, IOException{
        String test = "testisperfect";
        System.out.println(RCC4.keyGet());
        byte b[] = RCC4.keyGet().getBytes();
        byte plain[] = test.getBytes();
        **byte c[] = RCC4.encrypt(plain,b);**
        **byte p[] = RCC4.decrypt(c,b);**

        **System.out.println(new String(c)) ;
        System.out.println(new String(p));**

    }
    public static byte[] encrypt(byte[] plaintext,byte[] keyBytes)
    {
        byte[] e = null;
        try
        {
            Key key = new SecretKeySpec(keyBytes,"RC4");
            Cipher enCipher = Cipher.getInstance("RC4");
            **enCipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE ,key);**
            e = enCipher.doFinal(plaintext);           
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return e;
    }
    public static byte[] decrypt(byte[] ciphertext,byte[] keyBytes)
    {
        byte de[] = null;
        try
        {
           Key key = new SecretKeySpec(keyBytes,"RC4");
            Cipher deCipher = Cipher.getInstance("RC4");
           **deCipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key);**
            de = deCipher.doFinal(ciphertext);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
        return de;

    }

    public static Key getKey()
    {
        Key key = null;
        try
        {
            SecureRandom sr = new SecureRandom();
            KeyGenerator kg = KeyGenerator.getInstance("RC4");
            kg.init(128,sr);
            key = kg.generateKey(); 
        }catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return key;
    }
    public static String keyGet()
    {
        Key k = RCC4.getKey();
        byte[] b = k.getEncoded();
    BigInteger big = new BigInteger(b);
        String s = big.toString();
        return s;
    }

    }
```

When I press "Build file" it says process completed but at running file a message says

```
112670544188765215715791498302542646231


java.security.InvalidKeyException: Illegal key size or default parameters
       at RCC4.encrypt(RCC4.java:37)
    at RCC4.main(RCC4.java:23)


java.security.InvalidKeyException: Illegal key size or default parameters
    at RCC4.decrypt(RCC4.java:53)
    at RCC4.main(RCC4.java:24)


Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.lang.String.<init>(String.java:479)
    at RCC4.main(RCC4.java:26)

Process completed.
```

These Lines are indicated as *

Comment: I'm not sure why the downvotes. He gives sufficient information for the question to be answered.

Comment: The only thing that might be wrong is that he gives too much info considering the simple mistake. But the downvotes are a bit harsh on this.

Comment: What the..  `**byte c[] = RCC4.encrypt(plain,b);**`  Please post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).  Also, please use code formatting for error output.

Comment: I don't know whether SO noticed you of my revised answer that also answers your new question. If not, see below. If yes, please tell me and I will be a little bit wiser :)

Answer (score 3):

**Answer to original question:**

```
Key key = new SecretKeySpec(byte[]keyBytes,RC4);
```

should be

```
Key key = new SecretKeySpec(keyBytes, "RC4");
```

Also,

```
deCipher.init(Cipher.WHATEVER, keyBytes);
```

should be

```
deCipher.init(Cipher.WHATEVER, key);
```

Then it compiles, however there's still some issue with the application logic. That's up to you again :).

**Answer to new question:**

The problem was the unneeded usage of `SecretKeySpec`. Somewhere between `getKey()`, `keyGet()` all the `byte[]` games and `SecretKeySpec` it got wrong somehow. I didn't have the patience to track it, so I just deleted it and made the code somewhat more readable to make sure I didn't miss anything. I think you will still understand it since it still is basically your code and it is much simpler now.

```
import java.security.*;
import javax.crypto.*;

public class RCC4 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String plain = "testisperfect";
        Key key = RCC4.getKey();
        String encrypted = RCC4.encrypt(plain, key);
        String decrypted = RCC4.decrypt(encrypted, key);
        System.out.println(encrypted);
        System.out.println(decrypted);
    }

    private static String rc4(String plaintext, int mode, Key key) throws Exception {
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RC4");
        cipher.init(mode, key);
        return new String(cipher.doFinal(plaintext.getBytes()));
    }

    public static String encrypt(String plaintext, Key key) throws Exception {
        return rc4(plaintext, Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
    }

    public static String decrypt(String ciphertext, Key key) throws Exception {
        return rc4(ciphertext, Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key);
    }

    public static Key getKey() throws Exception {
        KeyGenerator kg = KeyGenerator.getInstance("RC4");
        SecureRandom sr = new SecureRandom();
        kg.init(128, sr);
        return kg.generateKey();
    }

}
```

Comment: Uhh, btw I just figured out your mistake in the original code.
That BigInteger fiddle is messed up. You could just use `return new String(RCC4.getKey().getEncoded());` as your keyGet() method.
However, I still think my new code is an improvement.

Answer (score 2):

You need import `SecretKeySpec` which is under package `javax.crypto.spec`.

Answer (score 1):

You're not calling the method correctly in that you're passing in the parameter type with the parameter. Parameter types are only shown when *declaring* a method, not when calling the method.

In other words, it's not

```
Key key = new SecretKeySpec(byte[] keyBytes, RC4);
```

it's instead

```
Key key = new SecretKeySpec(keyBytes, RC4);
```

You will of course need to have a keyBytes variable declared and initialized before trying to pass it into the parameter of this method.

Comment: But a new problem found ,it says

Comment: java.security.InvalidKeyException: Illegal key size or default parameters                                                             Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.lang.String.<init>(String.java:479)
    at RCC4.main(RCC4.java:26)

Answer (score 1):

```
package test;

import java.io.*;
import java.math.*;
import java.security.*;

import javax.crypto.*;
import javax.crypto.spec.*;

public class RCC4 {

    public RCC4() {
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException,
            NoSuchPaddingException, InvalidKeyException, IOException {
        String test = "testisperfect";
        System.out.println(RCC4.keyGet());
        byte b[] = RCC4.keyGet().getBytes();
        byte plain[] = test.getBytes();
        byte c[] = RCC4.encrypt(plain, b);
        byte p[] = RCC4.decrypt(c, b);

        System.out.println(new String(c));
        System.out.println(new String(p));
    }

    public static byte[] encrypt(byte[] plaintext, byte[] keyBytes) {
        byte[] e = null;
        try {
            Key key = new SecretKeySpec(keyBytes, "RC4");
            Cipher enCipher = Cipher.getInstance("RC4");
            enCipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
            e = enCipher.doFinal(plaintext);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return e;
    }

    public static byte[] decrypt(byte[] ciphertext, byte[] keyBytes) {
        byte de[] = null;
        try {
            Key key = new SecretKeySpec(keyBytes, "RC4");
            Cipher deCipher = Cipher.getInstance("RC4");
            deCipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, RCC4.getKey());
            de = deCipher.doFinal(ciphertext);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return de;
    }

    public static Key getKey() {
        Key key = null;
        try {
            SecureRandom sr = new SecureRandom();
            KeyGenerator kg = KeyGenerator.getInstance("RC4");
            kg.init(128, sr);
            key = kg.generateKey();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return key;
    }

    public static String keyGet() {
        Key k = RCC4.getKey();
        byte[] b = k.getEncoded();
        BigInteger big = new BigInteger(b);
        String s = big.toString();
        return s;
    }
}
```

Comment: The Code does not work , I do not know waht is the wrong every time the same error message the Illagle key size or default parameter